# How to resolve a "Object Variable Error" in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, automation, powerpoint

Run Time Error '91':

> Object Variable or With block variable not set

Written this below code but not able to execute because of Object Variable Error

```
Sub Create_PPT()

Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim shp As Object
Dim mySlideArray As Variant
Dim myRangeArray As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Dim sh4 As Worksheet
Dim sh5 As Worksheet
Dim sh6 As Worksheet

        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Close")
        Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trend")
        Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total_Cloud_Chart")
        Set sh4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AWS_Summary_Chart")
        Set sh5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compute_Chart")
        Set sh6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Storage_Chart")
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
        Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
        Err.Clear
        
        If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "PowerPoint Presentation is not opened, aborting."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If Err.Number = 429 Then
            MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate
    
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation
    
    mySlideArray = Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
    
    myRangeArray = Array(sh1.Range("A1:F14"), sh2.Range("A1:Q28"), sh3.Range("A1:P36"), sh4.Range("A1:AA26"), sh5.Range("A1:AA40"), sh6.Range("C1:AC28"))

For x = LBound(mySlideArray) To UBound(mySlideArray)

    myRangeArray(x).Copy
        
    On Error Resume Next
    
        Set shp = PowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With myPresentation.PageSetup
    
        shp.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (shp.Width \ 2)
        shp.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (shp.Height \ 2)
    
    End With

Next x

Application.CutCopyMode = False

PowerPoint.Save

MsgBox "Report Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: shp.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (shp.Width \ 2)

Comment: Seems like `shp` might be `Nothing` then.

Comment: No... I've set  Set shp = PowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

Comment: You have an on error resume next for that line, so if it fails to set then you'll get no error.

Comment: @LalSahab Have you verified `shp` by setting a breakpoint and checking?  Also, your code should always make sure an object is not Nothing.  Never assume.

Comment: Hi Warcupine, can you please help me how to fix that. As I'm just in learning phase in VBA coding

Comment: @BrianMStafford can you help me here please, unable to crack this error

Comment: Why Are you using " Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")"
and also using 
" Set shp = PowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange" ?
Doesn't make sense to me.

Without running your code in debug mode, everyone can only guess what the problem is. You have to step thru your code and check the Locals Window to find the missing object you are using.
You should get used to debugging. Take your time, it's worth it.


[Locals Window Explanation](https://masterofficevba.com/up-and-running-with-office-vba/getting-started-with-the-locals-window/)

Comment: "No... I've set Set shp = PowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange" ... which will be nothing unless something is currently selected, and even if so, you should use No... I've set Set shp = PowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to encapsulate 'On Error Resume Next' in a Try Function.

A Try Function does only one thing and reports true or false for success or fail.  The actual value from the operation in the try function is passed back via a ByRef parameter.

So, instead of this

```
On Error Resume Next
    
        Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
        Err.Clear
        
        If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "PowerPoint Presentation is not opened, aborting."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If Err.Number = 429 Then
            MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
    On Error GoTo 0
```

You would write

```
Public Function TryGetPowerpointApp(byRef ipPowerPointApp as object) as boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ipPowerpointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    TryGetPowerPointApp = err.number = 0
    err.clear
End Function
```

So, in your code, you can now say:

```
If Not TryGetPowerpointApp(PowerpointApp) then
    'do error stuff
end if
' continue on the happy path with PowerPointApp
```

There are several places in your code where the same strategy can be deployed.

You should look at the use of On Error Resume Next that is not encapsulated as above as BAD code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a serious recommendation. You'd need to learn to debug code in VBA because a missing object reference will come up again sooner or later.

Here's something to start with:

1. Direct Window
2. Step through code
3. Breakpoints
4. Locals Window